# Remove DataPoint from x-axis redraw Issues

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We are getting strange behaviour when removing a data point from a chart inside the load event.

We are using Highcharts JS v4.1.7 (2015-06-26).

When the series has more than 6 data points, and we remove the first data point, the chart is re-drawn correctly.  When the series has 6 or fewer data points, the removed data point label is still visible.  As well as this as a new category label is added which seems to be the original number of categories (6 for example). See screen shots below:

Working:
[image: Working Example]

Not Working:
[image: Error Example]

This is the load event code we are using on the example that doesn't work

```
$(function () {
// create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
                    series = chart.series[0];
                if (series.data.length) {
                    chart.series[0].data[0].remove();
                }
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]
    }]
});
```

});

Here are JsFiddle examples showing it both working and not working

- working - http://jsfiddle.net/arty_/418xcrq9/
- not working - http://jsfiddle.net/arty_/0cu5cu9t/

Any suggestions on how to resolve this

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the xAxis `minRange` behavior ([docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange)) which governs the minimum range the axis should show. This is defaulting to 5 in your case which explains why it tries to maintain a wider axis even when you are losing points. Set the minRange to something lower (eg 1) and you won't have any issues!

```
xAxis: {
    minRange: 1,
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
},
```

[New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cu5cu9t/1/)